# css class is no longer updated after changing hosts to HostBinding

Tags: javascript, angular

In my directive there is an `isOpen()` function which returns the status of a menu as `boolean` value.

```
/**
  * Checks if the dropdown menu is open or not.
  */
isOpen(): boolean;
```

Depending on this, the css class of the host changes. If I use the spelling with hosts metadata on the `@Directive` decorator, the css class will be updated correctly when I change the status.

```
host: {
  '[class.show]': 'isOpen()'
}
```

However, if I use the spelling with `HostBinding` inside the class, the css class doesn't change anymore.

```
@HostBinding('class.show') isShown: boolean = this.isOpen();
```

Apart from changing the binding to the host, everything else is the same. How can I get the host's css class to update itself with the HostListener method?

EDIT:
To put the problem into a context: it's a custom directive, inherited from Ngbdropdown

Comment: `Apart from changing the binding to the host, everything else is the same.` They are different. Your @HostBinding is equivalent to `'[class.show]': 'isShown'` host property. If you want the same behavior you should use it something like `@HostBinding('class.show') get isOpen() { ... }`

Comment: @yurzui can you please provide me with a small sample or a code snippet explaining your approach?

Comment: https://ng-run.com/edit/74WWXGidA1Ho0Thmvdvb Just click on `Hello Angular` to change `opened` status

Comment: @yurzui Great! It works great. If you could please formulate your comments as an answer, then I can accept them as the correct answer. thank you